# WindowsIdentity.Contains() not giving me correct result

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, active-directory

I am using `WindowsIdentity` to authenticate against AD to get groups a user belongs to. However, running the below code always returns true, no matter what I put in the Contains function parameter.

```
WindowsIdentity _user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
IdentityReferenceCollection _identityReferenceCollection = 
    _user.Groups.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
if (_identityReferenceCollection != null && 
   (_user.Groups != null && _identityReferenceCollection.ToString().Contains("blah")))
{
    MnuDataEntry.Enabled = false;
}
```

Am I using the contains function incorrectly? I have looked in the debugger and there is no group called 'blah'.

Comment: Did you find out what `_identityReferenceCollection.ToString()` returns?

Comment: Good question!
"System.Security.Principal.IdentityReferenceCollection"
So I should loop through it then?

Comment: I would loop through it, yes. Or try `_identityReferenceCollection.Any(x => ...)`, or something. Might need to stick `Cast<T>()` in front of `Any()`, and I don't know what `T` would be in that case, so... start with `foreach`

Comment: Ah, it implements [`IEnumerable<IdentityReference>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.identityreference(v=vs.110).aspx). You're in business.

Comment: `_identityReferenceCollection.ToString()` sweet jebus.

Comment: `_identityReferenceCollection.Any(ir => ir.Value == "blah")` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Will Go jebus [this other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390689/how-to-break-type-safety-in-c-sharp-clr-at-runtime?noredirect=1#comment75782156_44390689) if you're in a jebusing mood.